# Check if folder based on variables exists

Tags: bash

I'm creating a bash script, but it does not seem to check if a folder exists, when it's based on variables. Although the folder does exists, when I cd into it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

VAR1="/Users/nameuserhere/Desktop/";
VAR2=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`;
VAR3="$VAR1$VAR2";

echo "folder path: $VAR3";

if [[ -f "$VAR3" ]]
then
  echo "this/not does exists"
else
  echo "this/not does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: The `-f` tests for a regular file; to test for a directory, use `-d`.

Comment: Notes: **1** `;` are not required at the end of each line, unless you want to put multiple commands on the same line.  **2** VAR2 should be written `VAR2=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")`, backticks should be replaced by `$()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `-d`, as `-f` check if it's a file:

```
    -f FILE        True if file exists and is a regular file
```

Comment: @ObaApi You might want to use `-e` to check if *something* (file, directory, whatever) exists by that name. In scripts, I frequently run multiple tests with e.g. different error messages for "it doesn't exist" vs "it exists, but isn't the expected type of object".

Comment: nice thanks, in this case it's just a folder. It creates automatic screenshots in a folder named after today. The bash script makes a video of these screenshots with ffmpeg. This makes it possible to screencapture to an external hard disk with very low size also, without paying for software and improving your coding skills ;)